# My website is being zoomed in by Chrome and Firefox on Windows but I don't want to force users to change their browser configuration

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, zooming

my website is being zoomed in by Chrome and Firefox on Windows. This happens because I have the Windows Display set to Medium-125%, and Chrome and Firefox have this terrible feature of adjusting the websites zoom according to this selection.
In this way, despite having the browsers Zoom as 100%, the websites are shown as 125%.

I used the following piece of code to be sure of what was happening, and yes, with Chrome and Firefox on Windows, I have the browser zoom on 100% and the output of the following is 125. And if I decrease the browser Zoom to 80%, the output will be 100, and the page looks like how it should.

```
var browserZoomLevel = Math.round(window.devicePixelRatio * 100)
alert(browserZoomLevel)
```

Now:

- I don't want to change my Windows Display to Smaller-100% otherwise all icons will be really small, and I don't want to force future users of my website to change that as well, it wouldn't make sense!
- I don't want to make future users go to their browser configuration and change it to avoid this auto-zoom, it wouldn't make sense!
- Adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />` to my website `<head>` doesn't work.

I need to make the website shows up as 100%, not 125%. So, I want the website to ignore that Windows configuration without doing the suggestions above (in the bullet points), I would rather prefer using CSS or js to accomplish that.
Or in the worst case, for users with Windows Display set to Medium-125% I want to make the browser adjust to the Zoom 80%.

I'm sure a lot of people experienced this issue but I don't find any solution to solve it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm curious what you expect users at 200% or 300% scale to see.

Comment: The website is not meant for users with that zoom.

Comment: That doesn't mean anything though. If I press the zoom button on my browser, _something_ will happen when I hit 125%, then 200%, and so on. If you can say that the user is not meant to do that, then that contradicts your claim that you don't want to tell the user to keep their zoom at 100%.

Comment: What is not right is to make the websites appear as 125% only because the user has a Windows Display set to 125% BY DEFAULT. So what I mean is that the majority of the users has this configuration without knowing, so I don't want that the solution is at users side, especially because they didn't configure it in first place.

Comment: @JoshLee What I would like to do is somehow to program my website to ignore this. Because what is really annoying is that the user is being cheated, since that despite having the browser stating 100%, the websites are in fact with 125%. But if you don't have a solution, please don't bother.

Comment: I apologize for being blunt; I have been grappling with this problem for some time and have not come to a solution that works in every case. I won't flat-out say "this is impossible and also you shouldn't try", but perhaps you can describe _what_ exactly breaks at 125% and just try to fix that?

Comment: Thank you for understanding @JoshLee. What happens is that the registration form is cut off and some titles are out of the page, nothing that could not be solved maybe with a scroll or adding some margins. But if I could find a way to ignore that Windows configuration it would be much better.